# Set format of Excel sheet cell from General to Number using NPOI library

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, npoi

```
  currentRow.CreateCell(columnIndex).CellStyle.DataFormat = HSSFDataFormat.GetBuiltinFormat("#,##0");
```

I have written above line but it does not set format of excel sheet cell from general to number .It always remain general

Answer (score 2):

I spent many hours struggling with this, finally got it to work by calling CreateDataFormat() on the workbook object, like so:

```
....CellStyle.DataFormat = _workbook.CreateDataFormat().GetFormat("#,##0");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
//create workbook
var workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
//initialize workbook style
var wbStyle = workbook.CreateCellStyle();
//Initialize workbook dataformat
var currDataFormat = workbook.CreateDataFormat();
//Set workbooks style to desired format
wbStyle.DataFormat = currDataFormat.GetBuiltinFormat("#,##0");
```

This worked for me anyway.